# Paranoia gem restore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On the official [paranoia page](https://github.com/radar/paranoia)

There is a section about restoring model after it has been deleted.

```
If you want to restore a record and their dependently destroyed associated records:
Client.restore(id, :recursive => true)
```

However when I try this in my controller :

```
@user = User.only_deleted.find(params[:id])
@user.restore! :recursive => true
```

I get this error :

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

This is what I have in my Gemfile :

```
gem 'paranoia', '~> 1.0'
```

I see that this has been merged to master so I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here :

https://github.com/radar/paranoia/pull/91

**Update :**

When I change (as suggested in the answers)

```
@user.restore! :recursive => true
```

to

```
User.restore(params[:id], :recursive => true)
```

Get the following error :

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

**Update II:** 
Has anyone user this feature (recursive) with rails 3 ?

Comment: I would change it cause it says right here in this pull request https://github.com/radar/paranoia/pull/91 or you couldn't not find it again

Comment: removed answer, if you decide to go with fork I could help you if you don't know how.  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45145/room-for-london-and-rmagnum2002

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this file at the commit when the above patch was added. This was added on Version 1.3.2, So the changes are not available to you since you are running on 1.0.

https://github.com/radar/paranoia/blob/a0ec1c937f30b479f8e173b096a9298ed4b29cc7/lib/paranoia/version.rb